# What is the difference between AST traversal by Cursors and Nodes

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

I'm playing with libclang to parse small c++ files. I've seen examples about how to parse the AST trees.

As I understood AST constitutes of **ASTNodes** which has the type of either **Decl** or **Stmt**. To traverse the tree I can either use the ASTConsumer which visits **ASTNodes** or **CxCursors**.

What is the difference between these two traversal methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read some pages, I found some information about this subject. According to the clang [Tooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) documentation there are two tools (among other clang tools) :
 - Libclang
 - Libtooling

The CxCursors belongs to the Libclang library. The Libclang library provides the cursors to traverse the AST although the control on the AST is limited.

The classes Decl and Stmt are the part of the Libtooling. By defining a RecursiveASTVisitor and its corresponding visiting function one can traverse these nodes. With this method one can have full control over on the AST.

Answer (score 1):

Both are part of the same method of AST traversal as the cursors are pointers on AST nodes. If you look for a different method of AST traversal you should look into AST matchers. With that method you define a model of AST that you want to match against the AST of a source file. It can be a powerful method.

Here is an introduction to matching with Clang: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html

Comment: So the cursors are like high level methods to parse the underlying nodes?

Comment: I would have said walk through instead parse. Parse is for building up the AST.